# What does the noun "lucker" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does the noun "lucker" mean? It's not in the Webster, but Google does give search results for such key phrases as "I am a lucker" or "He is a lucker" (and those are not misspellings like "luckier" or "lurker"). So people DO use that word. I myself heard it a number of times. And if they use it, it should have some meaning. So, here is my question: what does the noun "lucker" mean?

Comment: Every newspaper makes an occasional error.

Comment: I agree with Jim's comment.  This is a misspelled version of *luckier*.  Or *lurker*.  Or something like that.  But I also agree that "word puzzle" type problems don't belong here.

Comment: Do you have a sample sentence where you heard or saw this word? It'd help to have some context. (as it stands it's totally unfamiliar).

Comment: @Mitch - Once I heard it at the baseball stadium in the USA. One of the viewers said about one player "What a lucker!" However, I am not sure what was going on to the player that he was referring to at that moment.

Comment: @brilliant: that situation is consistent with Annarita's answer from Urban Dictionary (where the player probably got lucky in some play).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found its [meaning on Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lucker):

> A word which is primarily used by retards in CounterStrike - although its use has unfortunately spread to other FPS (First Person Shooter) games.
>
> It means someone who gets 'lucky'. It is used mostly in situation where a person, considering himself/herself to be the best on the server (or at least better than the player he just got wasted by) says "Lucker!!!!". It can also be used as an incorrect replacement for "Lucky".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but one point is not clear to me here. "It is used mostly in situation where a person, considering himself/herself to be the best on the server (or at least better than the player he just got wasted by) says "Lucker!!!!"" - Does "wasted by" mean "killed by"? If yes, than how can he/she be better than the other player if the other player has just killed him?

Comment: I suppose that this is a term used to refer to a person who is really lucky, for example in a contest, in a raffle, in a game and wins a prize even if he/she has no great abilities. I have found an example: A: hey I won a ipod! 
B: you're such a Lucker! 
A: I know I am. This is doubtless a fluke.

Comment: @brilliant The point is that the "lucker" killed the sayer through sheer good fortune rather than because they were particularly skilful.

Comment: @Waggers - I see. Thank you. So, if I call someone a "lucker" that would mean more like "You got it, but you really don't deserve it", right? Which is probably quite different from "lucky you".

Comment: @brilliant Yep, that's exactly how I read it. But I wasn't familiar with the term before reading this thread!

Comment: @brilliant I read it in the same way. ;)

Answer (score 3):

One can only conclude it's part of a headline about an unfortunate and criminally-inclined chicken-farm worker ... *e.g.* **Unlucky Clucker Plucker on Way to Pen**.

Comment: Note that the question was totally changed after I answered.  It originally read: "Imagine you found a piece of newspaper, on which you could read only one word in the heading lucker - other words are smeared with mud and unreadable. Also, you can read the name of the newspaper and you know that this is a very well-respected newspaper and it never misspells words."  "Also the word is not written starting with a capital letter, so you know now it's not a name and it's not in the begging of the heading."

Comment: Sorry jwpat7. It seems that with the change of this question you were put into quite an awkward situation.

Comment: No problem.  I added my comment because someone marked down my answer, presumably unaware of context.

Answer (score -1):

i can clear this issue up. The term goes all the way back to COD 1. When playing the game i used (and still do use) the name Cupid Stunt. If you swap the initials then it makes a different phrase. (Name pinched from a Kenny Everett character). When i was killed by accident or by a fluke, then i would type in chat "YOU FUCKY LUCKER". This was then cut down to the term "lucker". How was i to know that it would take off and be a common phrase.
I also used the term "Loader" for someone who downloads a cheat or hack, but that one did not seem so popular.

Comment: *When i was killed by accident or by a fluke, then i would type in chat "YOU FUCKY LUCKER".* Are you claiming to have coined the word "lucker"?

Comment: You seem like a fan of spoonerisms.  Do you have a reference to this example to answer the question?