# What's the meaning of the noun "lucker"?

Tags: meaning, nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the noun “lucker” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44890/what-does-the-noun-lucker-mean)

What does the noun "lucker" mean? Yes, it's not in the Webster, but Google does give search results for such key phrases as "I am a lucker" or "He is a lucker" (and those are not misspellings like "luckier" or "lurker"). So people DO you use that word. I myself heard it a number of times. And if they use it, it should have some meaning. So, here is my question: what does the noun "lucker" mean?